# Calling a Function Inside Map Function

Tags: reactjs

I have a getNameByVal function and I want to call it inside component render() and the error message TypeError: getNameByVal is not a function. My code is as below. Anything is wrong?:

```
function getNameByVal(value){
    switch(val){
       case '0000':
         return "Online";
       case '0001':
         return "In person";
       ...
}
class App extends Component{
  ....
  render(){
    return <div>
     {this.state.checkedItems!==null?this.state.checkedItems.map(key=>getNameByVal(key)):[]} 
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Is `getNameByVal` declared inside of the class, or outside of it?

Comment: Please add more information around how your code is structured, it is hard to tell from this example where getNameByVal is declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was to write a component like this I wouldn't use classes so in case this is useful to you here is an example of how I would do it using hooks: https://codesandbox.io/embed/crazy-jones-2398c

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your function getNameByVal() is out of scope for the render().

What you can do is declare your function as a variable that will allow you to call it in your Map.

This is how you would declare it as a variable:

```
const getNameByVal = (value) => {
    switch(value){
        case '0000':
         return "Online";
        case '0001':
         return "In person";
    }
}
```

Place this inside your Rendor() { ... } or inside the delcaration of your APP/component.  Then you can call it the same way

Comment: it has red line under getNameByVal in the map function. 'getNameByVal' is not defined.

Comment: The above answers are both correct. I had a very stupid mistake in my local copy. My function was getNameByValue but I called it as getNameByVal.

Comment: upvote me, and ill upvote you :) Always happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Move your function inside your class like below and call it with `this.getNavByVal`

```js
class App extends Component {
  constuctor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.getNameByVal = this.getNameByVal.bind(this)
  }
  getNameByVal(value){
    switch(val){
       case '0000':
         return "Online";
       case '0001':
         return "In person";
       ...
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
     {this.state.checkedItems!==null?this.state.checkedItems.map(key=>this.getNameByVal(key)):[]} 
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I moved the function inside App component and calls it this.getNameByVal(key) and it returns the same error.

Comment: Oh sorry you will also have to bind the function in the constructor if you are using classes. I'll update above.

Comment: Thanks. I used arrow function getNameVal=(value)=>{...} and it still does not work. Should I call the function after render() and before return?

Comment: Did you see my other solution above @user788448 ?